# What is the average number of intersection- (aka, circle-) events in Fortune's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, memory-management, geometry, voronoi

I'm currently working on optimizing my working implementation of [Fortune's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm), an algorithm used to generate [Voronoi diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram), and I was wondering if the average **or** max number of intersection-events (also called circle-events) was known, for `n` seeds (i.e. the input points.)

Are these values known for some `n`? If so, what are they?

<sub>Also, as a meta question not worthy of a full post on meta, should this be asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), or [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)?</sub>